# Github - using someone elses repository

Tags: git, github

I'm busy with a project which uses some libraries from

```
git clone http://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code.git
```

I've downloaded the above code and put it in my code and now want post my code on github.

I also want to make sure that the latest code from adafruit is always used so is there a way I can put a link in my code to the adafruit  so that it always pulls the latest version.

Ive done some reading on git and I think this might be called a fork?  When putting my code do I put the adafruit code in my repository, or is there someone I can put a link in to the original?

Comment: While using the latest revision of the other project might be acceptable, usually you only want to use a specific revision so that your code doesn't break if a newer revision makes changes. If that's acceptable for you, you are looking for submodules: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules. I don't think you want a fork. A fork is a copy of a project which develops that project further, possible in a different direction. You seem to only *use* the library, not make modifications to it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're already a contributor to that project, you won't be able to push directly to their repository.

In that case the general usecase is to fork the project (i.e. create a copy under your name) and work on that. You can then create pull-request to ask them to pull specific changes from your repository.

[This GitHub Article](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) explains the process and also tells you how to keep your fork up-to-date (if you don't do anything special, it's basically just a snapshot).

Answer (score 1):

As you have already cloned the repository locally and made modifications, you should take a few steps to create a fork (for traceability to the original) and setup the appropriate remotes to synchronize with.

---

1. Go to http://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-Raspberry-Pi-Python-Code and click the "Fork" button
2. Copy the Git repository URL for your *new* Fork
3. On the terminal, in your project directory, add a remote:

`git remote add fork <repo-fork-url>`

4. Ensure your fork is up-to-date in relation to the original project

`git remote update

`git fetch

`git checkout master`

`git pull -rebase origin master`

5. Remove the existing upstream for master; Setup upstream to publish your commits to your Fork

`git branch --unset-upstream master`

`git push -u fork master`

---

From here on, you can edit and commit to your local repository, `git push` and `git pull` to sync with your Fork on GitHub, and `git pull origin master` to retrieve the latest commits from the original repository.

Comment: I believe that "-rebase" should be "--rebase".  I tried to edit the post, but edits must be at least six characters.  (An odd requirement for a programming site.)  Also, "--unset-upstream" doesn't work in some versions of git (e.g. 1.7.3.4).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by forking your can use pull request to send them your code for review which they merge in their project if they want.
To pull the latest changed from their repository see also:

```
git fetch upstream
git merge upstream/master
```

It automatically merges if no conflicts but sometimes there are so then you will have to do it manually.